# finding the critical points of a system of equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations

I have a question from a past paper where I am asked to find the critical point(s) in the second ($x<0$ & $y>0$) and third quadrant ($x<0$ & $y<0$) of the following system:

$$
X=x^2+y^2-5\\
Y=x^2+2y^2-9
$$

I know that to find the critical points, one needs to take the partial derivatives of these individual functions:
$$
\frac{\partial X}{\partial x}=2x\\
\frac{\partial X}{\partial y}=2y\\
\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}=2x\\
\frac{\partial Y}{\partial y}=4y\\
$$
From here I equate all partial derivatives to $0$ and then solve for $x$ or $y$.
I am only getting the critical point at $(0,0)$.

Can anyone please tell me where I made a mistake and if so, where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the critical points, we need to simultaneously find the zeros of $X = Y = 0$.

We have

$$x^2+y^2-5 = 0\\
x^2+2y^2-9 = 0$$

Subtracting the first from the second equation, we have $y^2 = 4$, so

$$y = \pm 2$$

Substituting that into the first, we find

$$x = \pm 1$$

We have four critical points

$$(x, y) = (1, 2), (-1, 2), (1, -2), (-1, -2)$$